# SQL Server : compare two tables and return similar rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I want to compare two tables, source and target, and get similar rows.

Compare source and target on `Id` one by one and:

- If matched and it's two or more on Target => select All matched from Target

  - If matched and it's two or more on Source =>
  - for first matched if it doesn't selected before

    - select Matched From target
  - else (IF it have selected before)

    - check for next one matched

I think need a recursive expression to check source and target one by one

Source

```
x------x---------x
|  Id  |   Name  |
x------x---------x
|   1  |   a     |
|   2  |   b     |
|   2  |   c     |
|   3  |   d     |
|   3  |   e     |
|   4  |   x     |
x------x---------x
```

Target

```
x------x---------x
|  Id  |   Name  |
x------x---------x
|   1  |   f     |
|   1  |   g     |
|   2  |   h     |
|   3  |   i     |
|   3  |   j     |
|   5  |   y     |
x------x---------x
```

Result

```
x------x---------x
|  Id  |   Name  |
x------x---------x
|   1  |   f     |
|   1  |   g     |
|   2  |   h     |
|   3  |   i     |
|   3  |   j     |
x------x---------x
```

Test data

```
declare @s table(Id int, name varchar(20))
DECLARE @t table( Id int, name varchar(20))

INSERT @s values(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (3, 'e')

INSERT @t values(1, 'f'), (1, 'g'), (2, 'h'), (3, 'i'), (3, 'j')
```

Comment: What does "for first matched" mean, considering that row order is not defined without an `ORDER BY` clause?  Along the same lines, what does "doesn't selected before" mean, given that rows are not filtered in any defined order?

Comment: Hi John, tnx for your attention. declaring a declarative language is defeacault!!.  i will update post.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need `Exists` operator to do this.

```
select * from @t t
where exists (select 1 from @s s where t.id=s.id)
```

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f766/1)**

Comment: I tried with Join, but this one is faster. I have seen execution plan of both, Join and Exists one. Up-voted.

Comment: @MihirShah - I will go for `Join` only when i need to select data from both the tables. If you just want to check the existence the always go for `Exists`

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    t.Id,
    t.name
FROM SOURCE s
INNER JOIN target t ON s.id=t.Id
WHERE s.Id IN (SELECT Id FROM target)
```

Comment: Do you really need that `where` clause

Comment: The `WHERE` clause is absolutely useless.  It will never filter out any rows because the join condition already ensures that it is satisfied by every row.

Comment: In any case, this does not address the requested varying results depending on number of matching source and target rows.

Comment: yes u r right Where clause is not required here ... my mistake